# Loop Invariants With Decreasing Iteration

Tags: loops, for-loop, iteration, invariants

```
from (temp := num)
until (temp = index)
loop
{
   data[temp] := data[temp – 1]
   temp := temp – 1
}
```

So, this is a loop from (temp) to when (temp=index)
I'm not sure what the loop invariant is because I've never worked with decreasing iteration before.

I'm thinking of something like:
(∃i : temp...index) • (data[i] := data[i-1]) 
but it's not correct because the base case doesn't work.